# Текущая директория плюс строка в PTCHAR

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, path

Есть функция, принимающая параметр PTCHAR path, этим параметром мне нужно передать текущую директорию (откуда запущен exe), склеенную со статичной строкой. Иными словами, функция должна принять путь до файла, лежащего рядом с моим exe. Как это сделать? Спасибо!

Comment: @Abyx http://imgur.com/oFPIXV6

Comment: используетй `std::wstring`: `std::wstring(path) + L"\\my.dll"` в случае юникода или `std::string` в случае multibyte либо специфические для Windows обертки типа CStringT

Comment: @Abyx http://imgur.com/a/CfeCw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать элементарно [`GetCurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa364934(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
PTCHAR pPath = NULL;
LPCTSTR lpFileName = L"File name.ext";

TCHAR szCurrDir[MAX_PATH + 1]; // +1 - this string is null-terminated
size_t pathLength = GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH + 1, szCurrDir);
if (pathLength > 0)
{
    wcsncat(szCurrDir, L"\\", pathLength); // include wchar.h
    pPath = wcsncat(szCurrDir, lpFileName, pathLength + 1);
}

YourFunc(pPath);
```